# Pattern to only match specifc characters in brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I need some advice with a regular expression in C#.
What I'm trying to match is everything between 2 characters (square brackets) but only when some characteres (,;) are not between the square brackets, I want to exclude those characters.

In other words I need to combine 2 expressions in a single regex.
I have this one: [(.*?)]
And this other: [^,;]

The two expressions work well when isolated, but I need the combination of both
I did not manage yet to combine them in a single expression, it would be nice if I could do something like this [(.*?)]**&**[^,;] but it does not work.

Here some realistic examples about what I need:

- ...[text1]...: **match: [text1]**
- ...[text text2]...: **match: [text text2]**
- ...[text,text2]...: **not match!**
- ...[text;text2]...: **not match!**

Please, any advice you can give will be very useful.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `@"\[([^,;]+?)\]"`?

Check it at [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C%5B%28%5B%5E%2C%3B%5D%2B%3F%29%5C%5D&input=...%5Btext1%5D...%3A%20match%3A%20%5Btext1%5D%0A%0A...%5Btext%20text2%5D...%3A%20match%3A%20%5Btext%20text2%5D%0A%0A...%5Btext%2Ctext2%5D...%3A%20not%20match!%0A%0A...%5Btext%3Btext2%5D)

Comment: @kirk-b yes, and instead of two problems, this guy gets two of the same answer

Answer (score 0):

Try @"\[[^,;]*\]"

Also, give http://regexpal.com/ a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use an alternation: This is an Example

```
    $test = preg_replace('/\[.*?\]|[\[\]=]/', '', $test);
```

The ordering is here important, so that at first matching brackets, and their content, are removed. This should work fine as long as there are no nested brackets.